# Elastic Search - java api for inner hit

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I made some query like below.

```
"query" : {
  "nested" : {
     "path" : "comments.votes",
     "query" : { ... },
     "inner_hits" : {}
  }
}
```

and I convert it as java api

```
QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(
    boolQuery
)
.must( // error here if i changed as '.innerHit()'
    QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("comments.votes", 
        QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must( ... )
    )
    .innerHit( new QueryInnerHitBuilder()) // error here
)
```

It's how I made java code on ES version 2.x.
Since I changed ES version 5.x, It's not functional at all. How should I changed it as ES 5.x version code?

Comment: Solved it. Change 'QueryInnerHitBuilder' to 'InnerHitBuilder'