# Elasticsearch Java API 5.4 - How to get the inner hits of a nested query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-java-api

I recently started to migrate from Elasticsearch version 2.4 to version 5.4. In version 2.4 I implemented some nested queries including inner hits, using the official Java API, which do not work in version 5.4 anymore.

Can anyone tell me, how to get the inner hits of a nested query using the Elasticsearch Java API 5.4? 
Unfortunately, I can't find any sources regarding this topic, not even in the Elasticsearch documentation.

My functioning nested query in version 2.4:

```
QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("classes.links",
    QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("classes.links.name", "xyz"))
).innerHit(new QueryInnerHitBuilder())
```

My attempt to get this query to work in version 5.4:

```
QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("classes.links",
    QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("classes.links.name", "xyz")), 
    ScoreMode.Avg
).innerHit(new InnerHitBuilder()) //Error here
```

As suggested here [Elastic Search - java api for inner hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42103028/elastic-search-java-api-for-inner-hit), I tried to replace *QueryInnerHitBuilder()* with *InnerHitBuilder()*, but it still does not work. I am getting following error:

*"Cannot resolve method 'innerHit(org.elasticsearch.index.query.InnerHitBuilder)'"*

Comment: Did you end up resolving your issue? It would help others if you provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The below implementation worked for me .

innerHit(new InnerHitBuilder())